# Cant debug Using QueueClient.OnMessage on a console app

Tags: c#, console-application, azure-servicebus-queues

I need to be able to debug the following console application to know if the messages are correctly deserialized or not.

However, when I press F5 on visual studio, I can debug this line:

string mensaje = message.GetBody();

but the following line seems is not executed, and the console APP closes and I can't even  see the message I wrote to the console. My best guess its because the nature of async calls with the OnMessage thing. but I am not sure.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("Microsoft.ServiceBus.ConnectionString");
                Console.WriteLine("Press key to continue");
                Console.ReadKey();
                QueueHelper.ReceiveMessageEmpresa("Empresa", connectionString);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }

public static void ReceiveMessageEmpresa(string queuName, string connectionString)
        {
            QueueClient Client = QueueClient.CreateFromConnectionString(connectionString, "Empresa");

            // Configure the callback options
            OnMessageOptions options = new OnMessageOptions();
            options.AutoComplete = false;
            options.AutoRenewTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

            // Callback to handle received messages
            Client.OnMessage((message) =>
            {
                try
                {
                    string mensaje = message.GetBody<string>();
                    Empresa empresa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Empresa>(mensaje);
                    // Process message from queue
                    //Console.WriteLine("Body: " + );
                    Console.WriteLine("MessageID: " + message.MessageId);
                    Console.ReadKey();

                    // Remove message from queue
                    message.Complete();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Indicates a problem, unlock message in queue
                    message.Abandon();
                }
            }, options);
        }
```

or how can I rewrite this method to return the object? or what would you suggest?

Comment: I updated the tag as you are using Service Bus Queues not Azure Storage Queues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've run into this exact problem this afternoon and after taking code out line by line found that it's something to do with using Newtonsoft. If you comment out your line:

```
Empresa empresa = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Empresa>(mensaje);
```

You should find that it works.

We've got round this by wrapping the JsonConvert functionality in another class which we're calling from our OnMessage method.

I've no idea why this is the case unfortunately, but I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Wow... I have had this problem too.

Hours of trying to debug this (because it just does nothing apearantly) and found a potential issue with Newtonsoft.JSON in combination with an Azure Worker Role.

Newtonsoft Package was installed fine. In my testing env. everything works too. As soon as I run the worker, it just sat there without emptying the queue.

So... before deployment to Azure, reinstall the Nuget package again (or use downgrade/update) if you experience this. You can also quickly debug this problem locally if you comment out SerializeObject or DeserializeObject calls. Or move the call outside of the Client.OnMessage statement, then you will see the error.

Answer (score 0):

Exctracting the message handling logic from Client.OnMessage() function into a separate method finally threw an exception (otherwise it failed silently).
And the problem in my case was that different versions of Newtonsoft.Json Nuget package were installed in the projects of my solution. 
I had to update them all to the latest version (9.0.1) and the problem was fixed.